# Why isn't the background image appearing inside my <div>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a background image just for this  part of my web page, I put my image as an id (fruit) but it isn't appearing. Here is my code:

```
   <div class="p-1 text-center bg-light" id="fruit">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto my-5">
        <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-normal">TrendyEats</h1>
        <p class="lead font-weight-normal">The Latest Food Trends</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Login</a>
        <p class="small pt-4">blablabla </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the css for the fruit id is:

```
#fruit {
   background-image: url('/Pictures/fruits.jpg');
   alt:"woops";
 }
```

The "alt" also doesn't appear.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Fixed, it appears I had to write "Pictures/fruits.jpg" instead of "/Pictures/fruits.jpg"

Comment: Nice question - points for format. - `alt` will only apply to images. It's an attribute. `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img`

Comment: `The "alt" also doesn't appear.` Yeah it wont, maybe describe what you're looking to do.. Some kind of `:hover` ? From the looks of it you want to put the `alt` into the HTML side of things.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380115/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-alt-attribute-for-div-elements/38380376

Comment: if you try background-color: pink; instead of background-image... does that work? ie. do you get a pink background?

Comment: @Pogrindis I see, thanks, I think I confused the picture syntax of html with css. The alt is an attribute for the html image tag and not css property. What I'm trying to do is add a background image behind the div that contains "TrendyEats" till "blablabla", so, a picture behind the texts. Does this make sense?

Comment: I got it fixed! It appears I had to write "Pictures/fruits.jpg" instead of "/Pictures/fruits.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that your relative link is correct. If I replace that with an external link the background shows up just fine.

You want to add the alt within an img tag in HTML- in your case you don't have this. If you are adding a background image via CSS, you may want to add a solid color as an alternative to display as a backup if your link were to fail.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
#friut {
  background-image: url("./Pictures/fruits.jpg");
  background-color: #000;
}
```

also check whether you have correctly linked the css file to the html page.

Comment: I got it fixed, it appears I had to write "Pictures/fruits.jpg" instead of "/Pictures/fruits.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Please check image url it's working,  [I am replaced it with content after #fruit] You can not place alt inside css you need to add on html image because it's html attribute, where you can add or set it with JavaScript.

```css
#fruit {
   background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg'); 
 }
 
#fruit:after {
  content: " (woops)";
}
```

```html
<div class="p-1 text-center bg-light" id="fruit">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto my-5">
        <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-normal">TrendyEats</h1>
        <p class="lead font-weight-normal">The Latest Food Trends</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Login</a>
        <p class="small pt-4">blablabla </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```