# How do I get ALT attributes for a onClick link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, alt-attribute

Consider:

```
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction22()"><img src="images/icon-exit.png" width="34" height="34" alt="Exit Fullscreen"></a>
```

I want a hover ALT tag for this Onclick link saying... "Exit Fullscreen"

Comment: use mouseover & mouseout js events to detect hover on your element and then grab the alt text from the img element and then create a element that acts like a tooltip

Comment: Could you explain why the anchor tag is used here? I’m finding it confusing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent to the "alt" attribute for div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380115/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-alt-attribute-for-div-elements)

Comment: Are you able to alter the HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the title attribute for this:

```html
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction22()" title="Exit FullScreen"><img src="images/icon-exit.png" width="34" height="34" alt="Exit Fullscreen"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the title attribute of the *a* tag like this:

```
  <a title="hello" href='/'>
    Hello world
  </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without involving a link

```
<img src="images/icon-exit.png" onclick="myFunction22()" width="34" height="34" title="Exit Fullscreen">
```

but in either case, just use title=